# Why GmailApp.getThreadById Keep saying invalid argument?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I cannot find whats wrong with getThreadById keep saying invalid argument.

Code as follows

```
function myFunction() {
  var ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  var replyThread = GmailApp.getThreadById(ID);
}
```

Is there any advice please.

---

Later I tried this code...

```
function myFunction() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1);
  var TID = threads[0].getId();
  Logger.log(TID);
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  var body = messages[0].getBody();
  Logger.log(body);
  var target = GmailApp.getThreadById(TID);
}
```

Now it works, and I found that the thread ID is different from the one in URL

URL shows 32 random captal letters and small letters.
The Id get from the getId method shows 16 random small letters and numbers.

Why this happen?

Comment: Please describe where you get the thread ID from

Comment: Thread IDs are not the same as Message IDs.

Comment: I copied ID from the end of an URL  <https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/{I copied from here....}>

Answer (score 2):

Now I found why this happen.

To get correct Thread ID from URL I have to set Gmail back to legacy mode.

Thanks